# Rename [KotlinTest] tag to [Kotest]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

Hello beautiful people!

I'm one of the contributors for the Kotlin library [Kotest](https://github.com/kotest/kotest), formerly named KotlinTest.

KotlinTest became somewhat confusing with Kotlin's Test from STDLibrary, and we decided to rename it.

As you can see, https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest points directly to https://github.com/kotest/kotest , and from the readme:

> Previously known as Kotlintest - From release 4.0 this project is now known as Kotest

As per [How to rename a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag) I believe only moderators can do this change, so could anybody help me with this?

The tag can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kotlintest/info

Comment: A synonym request may be better - the old name will still be known for a while, and will be searched for under the old name.

Comment: Perhaps. How do I propose a synonym?

Comment: See the [tag:synonym-request] tag and its associated [tag info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonym-request/info).

Comment: Can we do a synonym request ?